# Node.js Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:3000

Tags: json, server

I am encountering an error in my Node.js application and need some help resolving it. The error message is as follows:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1868:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1916:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (node:net:2065:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:109:8) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -98,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3000
}
```

i tried restarting my pc

Answer (score 0):

That means your localhost(127.0.0.1) has already using port :3000.

Try to connect with 8080 or 8000 port to deploy your application or you can kill process on 3000 port. I don't know your os so i recommend you to restart your computer if after terminate terminal processes and its still giving the same error.

You can search how to kill process on windows/linux/mac.